# Install Joomla component without manifest file

Tags: component, joomla-3.5, installation, manifest

I have taken over a joomla project from another consulting company, and I have made several improvements and changes to one of the components. Now my client is asking me to migrate this component to a similar project. Unfortunately, the component is missing its manifest file! As a bit of a Joomla newbie, I'm a bit worried I will get it wrong if I try to recreate it from scratch.

Is there a way to regenerate a manifest file from an installed component? Alternatively, is there a way to copy a component from one Joomla site to another one without having a manifest file?

Comment: Is it a custom built component or a 3rd party one? If a 3rd party one, you will simply be able to redownload it from the developer site and take the XML manifest from the zip.

Comment: Have you checked in /administrator/components/com_name/? The manifest file should be there.

Comment: @Lodder: It's a custom built component, so no such luck

Comment: @NicolaCiciliot: I have looked for it in that directory, but it's not there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my opinion you should create the package to install that component, it's quite easy to do.
Create a folder named as your component (com_name) with 2 folders and the manifest inside:

- admin : all files from */administrator/components/com_name/*
- site: all files from */components/com_name/*
- com_name.xml : manifest file

In the manifest file add just the meta information and the folder/files structure as explained in [this article](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component) and [this other one](https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files).

Zip the folder and try to install it on a clean joomla to test it, you can add database tables (if needed) manually to get things simple.